# Insert into Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tls1.2

I am new to Visual Studio. I have code, which runs in Notepad saved as .html. I would like to run this code in visual studio in an asp web forms project.

Here’s my code:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function parseTLSinfo(data) {
(data.tls_version.split('')[1] < 1.1);
    if (parseFloat(data.tls_version.split(' ')[1]).toFixed(1) > 1.1) {
        window.location = "https://www.yahoo.com";
    }
    else {
        window.location = "https://www.anyurl.com";
    }
    });
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check?callback=parseTLSinfo"></script>
```

When I run this code in visual studio I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.
I don't understand, how do I fix this? As far as I see it I think the code is fine.

Comment: You may want to edit the `script` tags so you are specifying a language since Visual Studio may be misinterpreting your code. For example, is it intended to be C#, VB or something else and how is the compiler supposed to know that without you telling it?

Comment: Yes, of course. This is what I have in notepad. My code in visual studio doesn't have scripting tags around it.

Comment: `<script>` is a script tag or do you have some other terminology at work here? If you are removing those pieces then I can easily see VS going, "Let's run this..." followed by a "huh, what is this?" as you aren't specifying that this is JavaScript to be interpreted in a specific way.

Comment: I have a project with functions in javascript in it. I just want to add this as a function into my project but I'm getting Cannot read property 'split' undefined error in the developer tools in chrome.

Comment: Is `data.tls_version` defined as a string? That would be my initial thought.

Comment: Yes, data.tls_version is a string. But why would that be the issue?

Comment: Ever heard of a `NullReferenceException`? The idea of trying to do an operation on something that is `undefined` is usually a no-no.

Comment: So then how would I define it? I have to run this function one way or another.

Comment: You would check to see that it is defined before doing anything on it. There is a chance that the server that makes the callback could run into an error and thus return something different than the expected successful call.